# How to make a "beautiful" URL with Django-Python

Tags: django, url-rewriting, django-forms

I have this URL product of a form:

`/capidahl?fecha=2014-06-23&hora1=00&minutos1=00&hora2=23&minutos2=59`

I want to make it shorter, like `capidahl/2014/06/24.`

how can I rewrite the URL using Django?

Comment: why the -1? @JustAnil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is easily done in django.  In urls.py, you specify the handler:

`(r'^capidahl/(?P<fecha>[0-9-.]+)/*(?P<hora>[0-9]+)/*(?P<minutos>[0-9]+)', 'my_function')`

Then, the function handles the variables:

```
def my_function(request, fecha, hora='12', minutos='00'):
    do something
```

Explained at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

Comment: thats regular expressions in urls.py?

Comment: Yes.  Beautiful, no?  You could even use [a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]+ if you allow any normal character

Answer (score 0):

here is an example about how to do it on model level (change it as you want):

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField( max_length = 255 )
    date_publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return 'capidahl/%s/%s/%s' %(self.date_publish.year, self.date_publish.strftime('%m'),  self.date_publish.strftime('%d'))
```